# How do I format a date inside of a Kendo ListView Template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI ListView and I'm using a custom template with it.  The problem I have is that the date is returning te full datetime format: 
`Thu May 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)` and I need it to be in a `dd/MM/yyyy` formate.  As the template is a script as per the documentation, I don't think I can just parse it with `kendo.toString` formatting.

Here is the listview code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<MyProject.Models.TheData>()
.Name("MyList")
.TagName("div")
.ClientTemplateId("template")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Model(model => model.Id("Id"))
.PageSize(4)
.Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "MyData"))
```

Here is the template script.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <label>Date:</label>
    #:Date#
</script>
```

Are there any formatting options I can apply to the above script template?

Comment: *I don't think I can just parse it with kendo.toString formatting* this means that you didn't tried or you have tried and it wont works?

Comment: You can include JavaScript within templates, see doc: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#create-external-templates

Comment: @ezanker I wonder if he tried something like `#=kendo.toString(Date, 'g')#`. It is not clear if he did.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, Yeah, I don't think he tried it...

Comment: I tried the kendo.ToString yes and no it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet. You can achieve the same thing by using kendo.string() and kendo.parsedate().

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
   <label>Date:</label> 
   #= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(data.Date), "dd/MM/yyyy"); #
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
   <label>Date:</label> 
   #= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date), "dd/MM/yyyy"); #
</script>
```

Comment: I get an invalid template error if I use semi-colon after toString. However, without them, this code works.

Comment: Indeed, loose the semi colon